# problemas com Axios e react-native. Axios retornando atributos vazios

Tags: php, laravel, api, react-native, axios

Tudo bem?

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para um cliente em react-native, devido a algumas integrações que o app precisa ter eu desenvolvi o backend dele usando Laravel 6.x. Até aí tudo bem, fiz todos os endpoints certinho e testei todos eles.

Mas, quando acesso um determinado endpoint, que é aquele que trás os dados de um produto, um dos atributos desse objeto, que é um array, vem sempre vazio. E não consigo achar o motivo. Alguém já passou por isso?

**Esse aqui é o método que vai retornar os dados.**

```php
public function recover($product)
    {
        $product = Product::with(['skus', 'gallery', 'categories'])->find($product);

        return response()->json($product);
    }
```

**Esse seria o retorno quando testo o endpoint no postman.**

```
{
"id": "453449b4-6311-4237-a88b-06b1ca41c281",
"title": "...",
"short_description": "...",
"description": "..."
"brand": "Probiotica",
"weight": 2.62,
"height": 30,
"width": 20,
"length": 20,
"tags": null,
"parent": "...",
"visible": 1,
"created_at": "2019-11-25 11:46:00",
"updated_at": "2020-01-06 12:13:54",
"deleted_at": null,
"skus": [
    {
        "id": "a0bc2293-df1d-4c57-8148-19d0085c3aaf",
        "product_id": "453449b4-6311-4237-a88b-06b1ca41c281",
        "title": "...",
        "price": "188.90",
        "discounted_price": "188.90",
        "stock": 4,
        "minimum_stock": 0,
        "created_at": "2019-11-25 11:46:00",
        "updated_at": "2020-01-06 12:13:54"
    }
],
"gallery": [
    {
        "id": "5ad17751-1b9a-43f1-b896-5ba97f4e23cb",
        "product_id": "453449b4-6311-4237-a88b-06b1ca41c281",
        "image": "...",
        "subtitle": null,
        "created_at": "2020-01-06 12:13:54",
        "updated_at": "2020-01-06 12:13:54"
    }
],
"categories": [
    {
        "id": "7b4eaa17-4a98-4f70-adfc-2c71cf0937d0",
        "parent": 0,
        "title": "MASSA MUSCULAR",
        "icon": "categories/7b4eaa17-4a98-4f70-adfc-2c71cf0937d0.jpeg",
        "visible": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-11-25 11:52:59",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-16 14:05:18",
        "pivot": {
            "product_id": "453449b4-6311-4237-a88b-06b1ca41c281",
            "category_id": "7b4eaa17-4a98-4f70-adfc-2c71cf0937d0"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "bd5cec08-9678-4f71-9ec2-38b2d02e6cf5",
        "parent": 1320136,
        "title": "Proteínas",
        "icon": null,
        "visible": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-11-25 11:52:59",
        "updated_at": "2019-11-25 11:52:59",
        "pivot": {
            "product_id": "453449b4-6311-4237-a88b-06b1ca41c281",
            "category_id": "bd5cec08-9678-4f71-9ec2-38b2d02e6cf5"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "0c2bc1ab-29a3-4cf2-8ac7-a72e204932d1",
        "parent": 1320154,
        "title": "Whey Protein",
        "icon": null,
        "visible": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-11-25 11:52:59",
        "updated_at": "2019-11-25 11:52:59",
        "pivot": {
            "product_id": "453449b4-6311-4237-a88b-06b1ca41c281",
            "category_id": "0c2bc1ab-29a3-4cf2-8ac7-a72e204932d1"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "dda4544b-8b57-4e80-aea1-bdde57fc9972",
        "parent": 1320160,
        "title": "100% Concentrada",
        "icon": null,
        "visible": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-11-25 11:52:59",
        "updated_at": "2019-11-25 11:52:59",
        "pivot": {
            "product_id": "453449b4-6311-4237-a88b-06b1ca41c281",
            "category_id": "dda4544b-8b57-4e80-aea1-bdde57fc9972"
        }
    }
]
```

}

**E esse seria o objeto que é retornado pelo GET do Axios dentro do aplicativo. Perceba que somente o atributo `skus` que vem vazio.**

```
{
"id": "453449b4-6311-4237-a88b-06b1ca41c281",
"title": "...",
"short_description": "...",
"description": "..."
"brand": "Probiotica",
"weight": 2.62,
"height": 30,
"width": 20,
"length": 20,
"tags": null,
"parent": "...",
"visible": 1,
"created_at": "2019-11-25 11:46:00",
"updated_at": "2020-01-06 12:13:54",
"deleted_at": null,
"skus": [],
"gallery": [
    {
        "id": "5ad17751-1b9a-43f1-b896-5ba97f4e23cb",
        "product_id": "453449b4-6311-4237-a88b-06b1ca41c281",
        "image": "...",
        "subtitle": null,
        "created_at": "2020-01-06 12:13:54",
        "updated_at": "2020-01-06 12:13:54"
    }
],
"categories": [
    {
        "id": "7b4eaa17-4a98-4f70-adfc-2c71cf0937d0",
        "parent": 0,
        "title": "MASSA MUSCULAR",
        "icon": "categories/7b4eaa17-4a98-4f70-adfc-2c71cf0937d0.jpeg",
        "visible": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-11-25 11:52:59",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-16 14:05:18",
        "pivot": {
            "product_id": "453449b4-6311-4237-a88b-06b1ca41c281",
            "category_id": "7b4eaa17-4a98-4f70-adfc-2c71cf0937d0"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "bd5cec08-9678-4f71-9ec2-38b2d02e6cf5",
        "parent": 1320136,
        "title": "Proteínas",
        "icon": null,
        "visible": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-11-25 11:52:59",
        "updated_at": "2019-11-25 11:52:59",
        "pivot": {
            "product_id": "453449b4-6311-4237-a88b-06b1ca41c281",
            "category_id": "bd5cec08-9678-4f71-9ec2-38b2d02e6cf5"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "0c2bc1ab-29a3-4cf2-8ac7-a72e204932d1",
        "parent": 1320154,
        "title": "Whey Protein",
        "icon": null,
        "visible": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-11-25 11:52:59",
        "updated_at": "2019-11-25 11:52:59",
        "pivot": {
            "product_id": "453449b4-6311-4237-a88b-06b1ca41c281",
            "category_id": "0c2bc1ab-29a3-4cf2-8ac7-a72e204932d1"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "dda4544b-8b57-4e80-aea1-bdde57fc9972",
        "parent": 1320160,
        "title": "100% Concentrada",
        "icon": null,
        "visible": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-11-25 11:52:59",
        "updated_at": "2019-11-25 11:52:59",
        "pivot": {
            "product_id": "453449b4-6311-4237-a88b-06b1ca41c281",
            "category_id": "dda4544b-8b57-4e80-aea1-bdde57fc9972"
        }
    }
]
```

}

**Essa é a action que uso para recuperar os produtos.**

```js
Axios.get(`${endpoint}/product/${id}`, { headers: { Accept: 'application/json' } })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      dispatch({
        type: Types.FETCH_PRODUCT,
        payload: data
      });
    });
```

O que pode estar acontecendo para que esse atributo venha vazio?
Ah, uma observação, caso eu remova os atributos `gallery` e `categories` aí ele vai me retornar o `skus` normalmente... o.O

Comment: Problemas locais é difícil saber.

Comment: como assim problemas locais? Você diz em localhost? Porque se for isso o problema é em ambos os locais, tanto localhost como em homologação...

Comment: Não é `localhost` no caso estou me referindo que isso está acontecendo no seu projeto e é de dificil compreensão para nós supor o porque está acontecendo isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido, na verdade, o que estava ocorrendo é o seguinte, ao recuperar esses dados, dentro do componente em que eu chamava a action eu estava, sem querer, fazer a mutação do mesmo, e por isso ficava na store o valor como null, sendo que eu havia dado um `.pop()` no array em questão...

Enfim, um erro bobo que me custo uma tonelada de tempo. hehehehe